# Having trouble with using AJAX to pass data from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, forms

Ok, so, first of all, I apologize for the question, but I am fairly new to web development.

I am trying to make a system in which the user can manipulate a database of events. I made it correctly with just php, but right now, I am supposed to add RESTful architecture to what I've already did, so I am trying to make REST API.

I am trying to make an example of it: `example.html` has a form with the name of an event that will be added to the database when submitted to `addEventToDB.php`, which is supposed to then return to the html page, but has created an object with whether the operation was successful and the name that was updated. The `midPoint.js` script should be able to get that object and based on that, create on the html page, a paragraph stating the success of the operation and name of the event. For some reason, this never works and only returns the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, instead of adding said paragraph.

This is my first experiment, but I think it's the best way to add REST architecture to the project.

example.html

```
    <form action="addEventToDB.php" method="post" class="form-group list-group col-6 offset-3">
      <h1 class="display-3"> Add Event </h1>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eventName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="eventName" id="eventName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="helpId">
      </div>

      <p id="demo">  </p>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add </button>
    </form>
```

midPoint.js

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var responseArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = responseArray.addResult;
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "addEventToDB.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

addEventToDB.php

```
$eventName = $_POST['eventName'];

if(isset($eventName)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO evento(`Nome`) VALUES ('{$eventName}')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result === true) {
        $responseArray->addResult = true;
        $responseArray->uploadValue = $eventName;
    } else {
        $responseArray->addResult = false;
        $responseArray->uploadValue = $eventName;
    }
} else {
    $responseArray->addResult = false;
    $responseArray->uploadValue = $eventName;
}

$myJSON = json_encode($responseArray);

echo $myJSON;

header('Location: experiment.html');
```

I am trying to make sure that this project uses REST and this was the best way that I could think of adding it, but I can't seem to make it work. That js file was supposed to get the data on the JSON file and print the paragraph, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You've got a serious SQL injection vulnerability in the code, please don't concatenate/expand variables into SQL commands. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Maybe this is a better start for your PHP code: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/ (Disclaimer: I'm the author).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array must be like this to be used by json_encode

```
$responseArray= array(
   'item' => array(
     'addResult' => true,
     'uploadValue' => $eventName
   )
 );
```